# Android - Unity3D freeze in splash screen on some phones

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, screen, freeze, splash-screen

I have a problem with Unity3D. I created a game with Unity 4.6.2f1. My problem is, game crashes after splash screen(Like trying to open itself constantly). The weird part is, game works on my phones and my tablets perfectly. I have Nexus 5(With Android 5.1.1) , Iocean X7S(With Android 4.2.2) , PolyPad tablet(Android 4.2.2) , Teclast X98(Android 4.4.4). I had some beta testers which have LG G2 , Samsung S5660 , Sony Xperia Z3 , HTC M8. From these 4 phones only Samsung make it run while others failed. I first though that this is because display bits. So I unchecked 32 and 24 bits Display buffer. Same result. Then I triend to change forcing Open GL ES version. I tried to build it with "Automatic" section - I don't know if its failed or not but It started to fade to black after a time even in my devices so I guess It's not an option for fixing. Then I tried to force it to use Open GL ES 3.0 , failed again. Then I read in somewhere that my AdMob plugin might be the reason , so I removed the components of AdMob from scenes and deleted all AdMob Plugin files. Same result. Since the crashed phones are not under my control , Its really hard to detect real problem easily because I really need to beg to my friends for every test since my testers are my friends and they have their own personal life, according to them its more important than testing my game whole day. By the way , I would like to add this too , like a month ago , everything were alright. It was running normal on my friends phone(The one who has G2). I'm getting suspicious from signing the apk. Because before signing it , while I was sending it without sign , It was working. That might be wrong idea of course. I'm not an expert so Im here for your helps. I really would like to know why this is happening and I want to fix this. Thanks!

Comment: maybe we can help, if you post some error logcat from the freezing phones.

Comment: Here , http://imgur.com/MvmLiOQ . This is from LG G2 (5.1.0) , thanks

Comment: are you using any plugins or 3rd party libraries in your game ?

Comment: I was using an AdMob plugin, first I thought that , this was the problem but this logcat belongs to a version with no plugin in it.

Comment: try to narrow the problem down by deleting step-by-step assets and features from your game, so that at the very end you end up with an empty scene, and also going back to an older unity version, where the problem did not occur.

Comment: I found the solution , thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay , I found the solution. It turns out that one of my script was responsible for this problem. So I deleted it and rewrite another script that do the same job. I assume, script was trying to use RAM over and over , so because of that, Adreno 330 type processors try to block the App's Open GL for preventing phone from total crash. This is only assumption of course. But If you are having a problem like I had , especially in Adreno 330 processors, try to check your codes first for any overloading.

Comment: would you mind being more specific than "use RAM over and over"? someone might stumble over this thread and might be happy to find a detailed answer. what did you do different in your rewritten script?

Comment: Actually I am not _that_ certain about RAM overloading but what I see is ,my old script was trying to gather information about System Language and changes the sprites according to this while Its getting information about screen touch , screen dpi , PlayerPrefs for highscore etc.Getting these informations shouldn't be a problem in normal way but I guess, while I'm changing the sprites according to language, other part of script try to change them with the tag I want to see in the scene for touching.So that creates a infinite loop that changes sprites which probably forces the processor.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issues, sometimes the problem was the memory of the device, null reference etc. also you could try forcing Open GL ES 2.0

srry can't make comments

Comment: I already tried forcing Open GL ES to 2.0 and I also tried forcing it to 3.0 with compressing textures either. Sadly , both ways failed.